# Accessing association in validates_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created a custom validator in order to validate some attributes in my `has_many` association.

**My class:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true 

  validates_with UniquenessMemoryValidator,
                 attributes: [:name],
                 collection: :addresses,
                 message: 'My custom message'
end
```

**UniquenessMemoryValidator:**

```
class UniquenessMemoryValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    attrs, message = options.values_at(:attributes, :message)
    collection = record[options[:collection]]
    puts "collection #{collection}" # it's nil
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I try to access my association (in this case: addresses) it prints nil.

So my question is: How can I access my "nested" *array* in validator?

PS: I can access any other attribute of my "record", less the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `send` if want to do it dynamically because it's usual method call:

```
collection = record.send(options[:collection])
```

Also, you can access to *nested array* only in `accepts_nested_attributes_for` validation with `reject_if`.
In `reject_if` you can pass *block* or *method*.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: { |attrs| ... }

#OR
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :my_method

def my_method
  #some logic that returns true for invalid record
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but it's not what I'm trying to achieve. I created a class validator and I want to perform a custom validation using my *nested* association on that class. After too many attemps, I discovered what's causing the *issue*: **The square bracket syntax**. I'm not able to access my association doing this: `record[assocation]`. If I use dot syntax, it works, **however** I can't use the dot syntax, because it's a general validator (dynamic).

Comment: @dev_054 but in this case you can use `record.send(assocation)` as I understand

Comment: That's it. Thanks for it.. can you add it to your answer, so I can check it.